# Google Cloud Build triggers don't fire when I push my repo

Tags: github-actions, google-cloud-build, build-triggers

I configured my build triggers to start as soon as I push to the repo on Github. This has always worked well.

Not since yesterday. It didn't work for a long time yesterday. I pushed again for a few hours, then it worked.

I thought it had something to do with this https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/zms09plx5zps case.

But today it still doesn't work.

On Github you can see the message: **Some checks haven't completed yet when committing.**
The affected build trigger says **"Queued - Waiting to run this check"**.

I've pushed more than once. However, the build triggers in Cloud Build do not start.

Comment: Have you tried to check this [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/troubleshooting-required-status-checks#:~:text=Due%20to%20path%20filtering%2C%20a%20pull%20request%20that%20only%20changes%20a%20file%20in%20the%20root%20of%20the%20repository%20will%20not%20trigger%20this%20workflow%20and%20is%20blocked%20from%20merging.%20You%20would%20see%20the%20following%20status%20on%20the%20pull%20request%3A)?

Comment: Could you share the screenshot of your Cloud Build Trigger configuration? Do check on any specific path filtering.